# Problem Upgrading System 76 Gazelle From Ubuntu 18.04 to 19.04

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, 19.04

I have a two-and-a-half year old Gazelle laptop from System 76.  It shipped with Ubuntu 17 installed.  It was upgraded to 18.04.  There's no CD drive, internal or external.

I (foolishly) decided to upgrade from 18.04 to 19.04 last night.

It downloaded, installed, and cleaned up without incident.  I rebooted and left it running when I went to bed.

It's still running this morning.

I see the following message:

> `A start job is running for /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 [11h 39 s/no limit]`

I also saw a message about crypt size needing to be set.

Have I bricked my laptop?  What next steps could I take to restore it?

Comment: You could possibly try the fixes listed [here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=194928), but as they are oriented around Mint, I cannot vouch for them or guarantee they will be safe or work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem with the help of System 76 support.  I downloaded a [new .iso image of Ubuntu 19.04](http://releases.ubuntu.com/19.04/) onto a flash drive and did a clean reinstall of the operating system.

It still wasn't easy.  My first attempt used a 32GB flash drive, but for some reason it got stuck, too.  A second attempt with a 16GB flash drive did the trick.

I've had to download and install a lot of software to get my machine back up to snuff, but all is well today.